# URLConnection, cannot find symbol

Tags: java, symbols, head, urlconnection

I´m trying to get a header field with the following code:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
 
public class Main {

  public static void main() {

   try {

    URL url = new URL("URL");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
    con.setRequestProperty("property", "name");

    System.out.println("\nGetting Response Header By Key ...\n");
    String userToken = con.getHeaderField("parameter");

    if (userToken == null) {
        System.out.println("Key 'userToken' is not found!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("userToken - " + userToken);
     
     
    }

    System.out.println("\n Done");

    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

But I´m getting the following error:

**Main.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
^
symbol:   method setRequestMethod(String)
location: variable con of type URLConnection
1 error**

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use [HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod-java.lang.String-) on a `URLConnection` variable. Luckily, `url.openConnection();` will actuall return a `HttpURLConnection`, so you can cast to `HttpURLConnection`:

```java
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
```